# How to communicate within a ActionProvider and the Main activity

Tags: android, view

I am trying to use a custom ActionProvider, below is the code, but I don't know how to control the view in MainActivity, How can I control the components which is in MainActivity in below code "OnClick" function?

```
public class CustomActionProvider extends ActionProvider {
Context mContext;
public CustomActionProvider(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateActionView(MenuItem forItem) {
      LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
      View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar,null);
      Button red = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_red);

      red.setOnClickListener(
              new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                           //What should I put here to control components of MainActivity

                    }
                }
              );
      return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For an ActionProvider to communicate with an Activity I see 2 solutions:

1) Use the LocalBroadcastManager. Send a broadcast Intent from the ActionProvider and implement a BroadcastReceiver in the Activity. The data must be Parcelable/Serializable.

2) Create a public method on your ActionProvider to set a listener. Retrieve the ActionProvider instance from the MenuItem in the Activity's onCreateOptionMenu() method and call the setListener() method to set your Activity's listener.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a safe/proper way to do it, but:

In your `Activity`:

```
//Define an Activity static member
private static Activity myActivity;
//Define getter method
public static Activity getMyActivity(){
    return myActivity;
}
//In onCreate set myActivity=this.
```

Then in your `ActionProvider`:

```
private Activity myActivity = MyActivity.getMyActivity();
```

That's how I made it in my application too, if anyone has a better suggestion he/she's welcome! :)

**EDIT**
You can also send Broadcast messages and extend your own `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Keeping a static reference to an Activity is forbidden since it creates memory leaks.